# C++ Should a function prototype use the namespace

Tags: c++

In a header file, should I prototype functions using the full namespace::type or bring the type into scope with using namespace::type?

```
#pragma once
...
void m_print(std::string msg);
```

vs

```
#pragma once
...
using std::string;
void m_print(string msg);
```

Comment: No. That `using` will leak into every other file that includes your header.

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off topic on SO. I'd prefer the former though, as you should always minimize your impacts on other files which import your headers.

Comment: here is what the [C++ Core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rs-using-directive) has to say about using in headers.